# UIScrollView changes content offset on presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

A `UIScrollView` in my view hierarchy is acting funky whenever I present a modal view controller  above it. It automatically adjusts the content offset and moves my content down about 40 pixels. I can't seem to figure out how to stop this.

After snooping around I've found that the `presentModalViewController` somehow triggers the private method `_adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary` on my `UIScrollView` and this is what is changing the offset.

Any idea if this is a bug on Apple's part? Or is something getting set screwy in my `UIScrollView`? Anyway to disable this `_adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary` method or at least this side effect?

Comment: FYI, I'm working around this with a Category on my ViewController presentModalViewController method that saves the problem UIScrollView contentOffset and then sets it back. I also reload the Data in the UIView hierarchy when i dismissModalViewController.

I'd still like to find a more elegant solution since I unnecessarily have to reload the data and this has processing overhead

Comment: Did you try setting the property `scrollEnabled` to NO & then back to YES ?

Comment: I'll try that. Seems like a strange fix

Comment: Any luck with this yet @JustinMilo ?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not fancy, I solved this resetting the content offset in the viewDidAppear of the presentingViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the property automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets of your ViewController, that contains the UIScrollView, to "NO"